# AsyncTask keeps on giving output and updating my list

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

This is my `AsyncTask` code which , I am using to populate custom listview . But I think something is wrong with this code .This piece of code keeps on running , I don't know how many times. But at the end it is giving me right results after so many updates on `TextView` (designation). This is not only degrading the performance of my application but also showing multiple updates on `TextView` before reaching to result.

I am getting data in `desig[0]` variable , have a look on my code .

Data is coming from azure But don't worry if you are not an azure guy . Just help me on Java part.

**One more thing this whole code is inside the `getView()` method**.

```
    final String[] desig = new String[1];

                try {
                    mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                            "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                            "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                            getContext());

                    mUser = mClient.getTable(User.class);

                    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                            try {
                                final MobileServiceList<User> result =
                                        mUser.where().field("name").eq(currentItem.getFrom()).select("designation").execute().get(); 



                                int counter=
                                        mUser.where().select("designation").execute().get().getTotalCount();
                                Log.v("counteeeerr", String.valueOf(counter));
                                for (User item : result) {
                                    // Log.i(TAG, "Read object with ID " + item.id);
                                    desig[0] = item.getDesignation();
                                    Log.v("FINALLY DESIGNATION IS", desig[0]);


                                }
                                return true;

                            } catch (Exception exception) {
                                exception.printStackTrace();
                                return false;
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aVoid) {
                            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                           // gb.setDesignation(desig[0]);

                        if(aVoid) {
                            designation.setText(desig[0]);
                        }

                        }
                }.execute();
```

Here is my `LogCat`

```
14 06:39:20.351  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:39:20.351  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ Project Head, Mojokarma
07-14 06:39:22.851  26899-26899/com.mojokarma.mojokarma D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1846K, 19% free 8126K/10028K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
07-14 06:39:22.855  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:39:22.855  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ Project Head, Mojokarma
07-14 06:39:25.099  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:39:25.099  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ CFO , HP
07-14 06:39:27.423  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:39:27.423  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ CFO , HP
07-14 06:39:29.679  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:39:29.679  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ Project Head, Mojokarma
07-14 06:39:31.903  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:39:31.903  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ Project Head, Mojokarma
07-14 06:39:34.083  26899-27003/com.mojokarma.mojokarma D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1769K, 19% free 8156K/10028K, paused 7ms, total 10ms
07-14 06:39:34.363  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:39:34.363  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ CFO , HP
07-14 06:39:36.615  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:39:36.615  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ CFO , HP
07-14 06:39:39.007  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:39:39.007  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ Project Head, Mojokarma
07-14 06:39:41.491  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:39:41.491  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ Project Head, Mojokarma
07-14 06:39:43.847  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:39:43.847  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ CFO , HP
07-14 06:39:46.111  26899-27003/com.mojokarma.mojokarma D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1812K, 19% free 8160K/10028K, paused 5ms, total 7ms
07-14 06:39:46.675  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:39:46.675  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ CFO , HP
07-14 06:39:49.015  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:39:49.015  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ Project Head, Mojokarma
07-14 06:39:51.243  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:39:51.243  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ Project Head, Mojokarma
07-14 06:39:53.515  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:39:53.515  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ CFO , HP
07-14 06:39:55.723  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:39:55.723  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ CFO , HP
07-14 06:39:57.575  26899-27003/com.mojokarma.mojokarma D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1818K, 19% free 8161K/10036K, paused 5ms, total 7ms
07-14 06:39:58.111  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:39:58.111  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ Project Head, Mojokarma
07-14 06:40:00.375  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:40:00.375  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ Project Head, Mojokarma
07-14 06:40:02.695  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:40:02.695  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ CFO , HP
07-14 06:40:05.519  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:40:05.519  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ CFO , HP
07-14 06:40:07.775  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:40:07.775  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ Project Head, Mojokarma
07-14 06:40:09.955  26899-27003/com.mojokarma.mojokarma D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1825K, 19% free 8154K/10036K, paused 5ms, total 6ms
07-14 06:40:10.515  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:40:10.515  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ Project Head, Mojokarma
07-14 06:40:12.823  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:40:12.823  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ CFO , HP
07-14 06:40:15.103  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:40:15.103  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ CFO , HP
07-14 06:40:17.523  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:40:17.523  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ Project Head, Mojokarma
07-14 06:40:20.475  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:40:20.475  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ Project Head, Mojokarma
07-14 06:40:21.807  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1809K, 19% free 8160K/10036K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
07-14 06:40:23.047  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:40:23.047  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ CFO , HP
07-14 06:40:25.331  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:40:25.331  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ CFO , HP
07-14 06:40:27.511  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:40:27.511  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ Project Head, Mojokarma
07-14 06:40:29.695  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:40:29.695  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ Project Head, Mojokarma
07-14 06:40:31.987  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:40:31.987  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ CFO , HP
07-14 06:40:33.063  26899-27003/com.mojokarma.mojokarma D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1818K, 19% free 8151K/10036K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
07-14 06:40:34.451  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/counteeeerr﹕ 4
07-14 06:40:34.451  26899-26997/com.mojokarma.mojokarma V/FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ CFO , HP
```

**Expected Result:-**

These four lines , I am expecting :-

FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ Project Head, Mojokarma

FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ Project Head, Mojokarma

FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ CFO , HP

FINALLY DESIGNATION IS﹕ CFO , HP

**I am getting:-**

You can see , I am getting same results again and again .Let me know if you want something else .

Comment: Currently `AsyncTask` is executing according to number of times `getView` method is called

Comment: I don't think so . Okk should i post my MainActivity code .

Comment: You should execute your asynctask outside your getView().

Comment: then how can i update each row of custom list view

Answer (score 1):

1. Never put code inside getView() of adapter.
2. You should do data fetching in Fragment/Activity and pass that data array in adapter
3. This scenario is correct, as getView() is called multiple time during it's life cycle, which is not in our control.

Comment: give me some sample code if you have any, or some link will be helpful

Comment: You can see sample here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24608604/passing-data-for-list-view-from-asynctask-to-a-custom-list-adapter-class

Comment: *Never put code inside getView().* ... hehe, could you be more precisely